# nested ifs with multiple sumifs based on changing criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

I am having trouble with this formula and would like to know if I am even building it in the correct order or how i can change it to get the desired result.  Getting formula missing an opening or closing parenthesis error:

```
=IF(BH2="PPD TO FSC",SUMIFS('ALL BIDS'!R:R,'ALL BIDS'!D:D,BV2,'ALL BIDS'!E:E,I2,'ALL BIDS'!W:W,'DC TOOL'!U2,'ALL BIDS'!G:G,'DC TOOL'!V2,'ALL BIDS'!H:H,'DC TOOL'!M2),SUMIFS(FREIGHT!Z:Z,FREIGHT!Q:Q,'DC TOOL'!F2,FREIGHT!M:M,H2,FREIGHT!O:O,"PPD",FREIGHT!AA:AA,GRIDS!$U$3),IF(BH2="PPD TO GDC",SUMIFS('ALL BIDS'!R:R,'ALL BIDS'!D:D,F2,'ALL BIDS'!E:E,I2,'ALL BIDS'!W:W,'DC TOOL'!U2,'ALL BIDS'!G:G,'DC TOOL'!V2,'ALL BIDS'!H:H,'DC TOOL'!M2),SUMIFS(FREIGHT!Z:Z,FREIGHT!Q:Q,'DC TOOL'!F2,FREIGHT!M:M,H2,FREIGHT!O:O,"PPD",FREIGHT!AA:AA,GRIDS!$U$3))
```

Comment: Microsoft Excel, since ancient times, supports named ranges. If your ranges  are fixed, assign names to them. This will make your formula (and life) easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want 3 different possible SUMIFS, with the logic being as follows:

IF BH2 = "x" `SUMIFS1`, IF BH2 = "y" `SUMIFS2` else `SUMIFS3` so you need to write that like this:

`=IF(BH2="PPD TO FSC",SUMIFS('ALL BIDS'!R:R,'ALL BIDS'!D:D,BV2,'ALL BIDS'!E:E,I2,'ALL BIDS'!W:W,'DC TOOL'!U2,'ALL BIDS'!G:G,'DC TOOL'!V2,'ALL BIDS'!H:H,'DC TOOL'!M2),IF(BH2="PPD TO GDC",SUMIFS('ALL BIDS'!R:R,'ALL BIDS'!D:D,F2,'ALL BIDS'!E:E,I2,'ALL BIDS'!W:W,'DC TOOL'!U2,'ALL BIDS'!G:G,'DC TOOL'!V2,'ALL BIDS'!H:H,'DC TOOL'!M2),SUMIFS(FREIGHT!Z:Z,FREIGHT!Q:Q,'DC TOOL'!F2,FREIGHT!M:M,H2,FREIGHT!O:O,"PPD",FREIGHT!AA:AA,GRIDS!$U$3)))`